# How can I scrape data from a text table using Python?

Tags: python, scrape

I have the following text and I would like to scrape the data items and save them in excel.  Is there a way to do this in Python?

```
text = """
                                       ANNUAL COMPENSATION                   LONG-TERM COMPENSATION
                              --------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
                                                                                AWARDS            PAYOUTS
                                                                      -------------------------- ----------
                                                                                      SECURITIES
                                                          OTHER         RESTRICTED    UNDERLYING            ALL OTHER
   NAME AND PRINCIPAL                                     ANNUAL           STOCK       OPTIONS/     LTIP    COPMPENSA-
        POSITION         YEAR SALARY ($)   BONUS ($) COMPENSATION ($) AWARD(S) ($)(1) SAR'S (#)  PAYOUTS($) TION($)(3)
   ------------------    ---- ----------   --------- ---------------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
JOHN W. WOODS            1993  $595,000    $327,250    There is no      $203,190.63     18,000               $ 29,295
 Chairman, President, &  1992  $545,000    $245,250    compensation      166,287.50     18,825    (2) Not    $ 29,123
 Chief Executive Officer 1991  $515,000    $283,251   required to be                    45,000   Applicable
 of AmSouth & AmSouth                                  disclosed in
 Bank N.A.                                             this column.
C. STANLEY BAILEY        1993  $266,667(4) $133,333                      117,012.50      4,500               $ 11,648
 Vice Chairman, AmSouth  1992  $210,000    $ 84,000                       42,400.00      4,800               $ 12,400
 & AmSouth Bank N.A.     1991  $186,750    $ 82,170                      161,280.00      9,750
C. DOWD RITTER           1993  $266,667(4) $133,333                      117,012.50      4,500               $ 13,566
 Vice Chairman, AmSouth  1992  $210,000    $ 84,000                       42,400.00      4,800               $ 12,920
 & AmSouth Bank N.A.     1991  $188,625    $ 82,995                      161,280.00      9,750
WILLIAM A. POWELL, JR.   1993  $211,335    $ 95,101                                     11,000               $124,548
 President, AmSouth      1992  $330,000    $132,000                       98,050.00     11,100               $ 22,225
 and Vice Chairman,      1991  $308,000    $169,401                                     24,000
 AmSouth Bank N.A.
 Retired in 1993
A. FOX DEFUNIAK, III     1993  $217,000    $ 75,950                       52,971.88      4,500               $ 11,122
 Senior Executive Vice   1992  $200,000    $ 62,000                       42,400.00      4,800               $ 11,240
 President, Birmingham   1991  $177,500    $ 78,100                      161,280.00      9,750
 Banking Group,
 AmSouth Bank N.A.
E. W. STEPHENSON, JR.    1993  $177,833    $ 71,133                       52,971.88      3,400               $  9,256
 Senior Executive Vice   1992  $150,000    $ 45,000                       27,825.00      3,150               $  8,560
 President, AmSouth      1991  $140,000    $ 52,488                      107,520.00      6,750
 and Chairman & Chief
 Executive Officer,
 AmSouth Bank of Florida
"""
```

Right now, I'm just trying to get it in a csv style format with an '|' symbol to separate the data items and then manually extract the data to excel:

```
tmp = open('tmp.txt','w')
tmp.write(text)
tmp.close()

data1 = []

for line in open('tmp.txt'):
    line = line.lower()
    if 'SALARY' in line:
        line = line.replace(' ','|')
    line = line.replace('--', '')
    line = line.replace('- -', '')
    line = line.replace('-  -', '')
    line = line.replace('(1)', '')
    line = line.replace('(2)', '')
    line = line.replace('(3)', '')
    line = line.replace('(4)', '')
    line = line.replace('(5)', '')
    line = line.replace('(6)', '')
    line = line.replace('(7)', '')
    line = line.replace('(8)', '')
    line = line.replace('(9)', '')
    line = line.replace('(10)', '')
    line = line.replace('(11)', '')
    line = line.replace('(S)', '')
    line = line.replace('($)', '')
    line = line.replace('(#)', '')
    line = line.replace('$', '')
    line = line.replace('-0-', '0')
    line = line.replace(')', '|')
    line = line.replace('(', '|-')
    line = re.sub(r'\s(\d)', '|\\1', line)
    line = line.replace(' ', '')
    line = line.replace('||', '|')
    data1.append(line)
data = ''.join(data1)
```

The problem is that I have to do this thousands of times and it would take forever to go through each table and save the items I need.  Is there a way to create a dictionary that will keep track of things like year, salary, bonus, other annual compensation, etc for each individual listed in the far left column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code to get you started:

```
text = """JOHN ...""" # text without the header

# These can be inferred if necessary
cols = [0, 24, 29, 39, 43, 52, 71, 84, 95, 109, 117]

db = []
row = []
for line in text.strip().split("\n"):
    data = [line[cols[i]:cols[i+1]] for i in xrange((len(cols)-1))]
    if data[0][0] != " ":
        if row:
            db.append(row)
        row = map(lambda x: [x], data)
    else:
        for i, c in enumerate(data):
            row[i].append(c)
print db
```

This will produce an array with an element per person. Each element will be an array of all the columns, and that will hold an array of all the rows. This way you can easily access the different years, or do things like concatenate the person's title:

```
for person in db:
    print "Name:", person[0][0]
    print " ".join(s.strip() for s in person[0][1:])
    print
```

Will yield:

```
Name: JOHN W. WOODS           
Chairman, President, & Chief Executive Officer of AmSouth & AmSouth Bank N.A.

Name: C. STANLEY ...
```

Comment: This is great.  Thank you so much.  Is there an easy way to infer the columns if they are not uniformly [0, 24, 29, 39, 43, 52, 71, 84, 95, 109, 117]?

Comment: Yes, look for characteristics. You could for instance take the line with `-----` below the title and split that using `string.split(' ')`. You will have to look at several different document and see if you can pick out characteristics that always hold true.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a series of generators to make successive passes at the data to reduce noise and complexity.

This is **not** an easy problem to solve in any programming language.

```
def strip_top( source_text ):
    src= iter( source_text )
    for line in src:
        if line.rstrip().startswith("AWARDS"):
            next( src )
            break
    for line in src:
        yield line

def columnize( source_text ):
    """Assumes strip_top or similar to remove confusing extra headers"""
    for line in src:
        yield line[0:24], line[25:30], ... for each coumn

def collapse_headers( source_text ):
    """Assumes columnize( strip_top())."""
    src= iter( source_text )
    headings= [ [] for i in range(9) ]
    for line in src:
        if line[0] == "------------------":
            break
        for col in range(9):
            headings[col].append(line[col].strip())
    yield [ " ".join(h) for h in headings ]
    for line in src:
        yield line

etc.
```

Then, your "main" program assembles these transformations into a pipeline.

```
with open("some file","r") as text:
    for line in collapse_headers( columnize( strip_top( text ) ) ):
        # further cleanup?  
        # actual processing
```

This allows you to "tweak" each piece of the transformation sequence separately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, separating the columns is easy, they're fixed width, so you can do:

```
cells = [rowtext[0:24], rowtext[25:29], ...]
```

Separating the rows is a bit harder. It looks like you can handle the headers separately, and then check

```
cells[0] == cells[0].upper()
```

to see if you should start a new block of rows (i.e. when the first cell in the row is in block caps). Of course, I'm assuming that your thousands of files all have pretty much exactly the same format.

Once you've got the data into a usable format, collating it in Python is the easy bit. You can stick it all in a dictionary, or if it's going to be too big, write it to disk as a big CSV file, or an sqlite database.